# NodeJS - techniques to avoid 429 too many requests error on local?

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes

I'm hitting to 3rd party API, and the endpoint can handle 1 req in ~2s.

A naive way is to spin up a couple of servers on DigitalOcean or similar to make it possible to send more requests. Basically, one responsibility for each server, so the ~2s wait time is not a problem.

However, are there some techniques I could do so locally?

Docker came into my mind, but before I start figuring things out I think its helpful to ask here first is that even possible?

Comment: In this context, Docker is just a way to package and run software, and Kubernetes a way to run it in a dedicated cluster.  Neither technology on its own will provide you with client-side rate-limiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spinning up more containers does mean you could send more requests per second, in theory.

*BUT*, every container will still have the same exit point - be it your PC, laptop or router (all requests originate from the same source). This means, depending on how 3rd party enforces QPS restrictions, all but one request every 2 seconds will be rejected.

What you need in this scenario is a botnet, which I highly discourage, or other type of distributed system, with multiple exit points.

**Bypassing 3rd party restrictions may be (probably is) against EULA. Check the 3rd party agreement, to make sure you are not breaking it.**

Comment: "every container will still have the same exit point" - this is real issue - for example, I'm having the same problem for my company - I have asked question related to that in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71941651/multiple-unique-network-ip-addresses-in-the-same-server